Breakdown of the fourier series identity $e_n e_m = e_{n+m}$ on a perturbed torus
I would like to apologize for leaving things a bit vague. I think my question could be stated much more precisely but right now that is difficult for me to do. I nevertheless think it is an interesting question and I hope you find so too!
Let $\mathbb{T}^d$ be the torus and consider on it the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_g = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_i(\sqrt{g} g_{i,j} \partial_j)$ , $i, j = 1, \dots, d$,where $g \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^d; \mathbb{R}^{d \times d})$ is a smooth metric. Famously. if $g = Id$ then our Eigenbasis in $L^2(\mathbb{T}^d; \mathbb{R})$ is $e_n = e^{i n x}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^d$. In particular we have the "convolution theorem"
$$
e_n e_m = e_{n+m} \,,
$$
I call this the convolution theorem because it makes it possible to understand multiplication in physical space as convolution in Fourier space.
I am interested in the breakdown of this identity when $g = Id + \epsilon \tilde{g}$.
As far as I understand for small $\epsilon > 0$ the eigenvalues should vary continuously with respect to $\epsilon$. In particular I would hope that there is a consistent way to refer to the new modified Eigenbasis as $e_n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Of course this might requires some assumptions.
In this case, can we prove an identity of the type
$$
e_n e_m = e_{n+m} + \epsilon R_{n,m} + o(\epsilon) \,.
$$
where $R_{n,m} = R_{n,m}(g)$ is a remainder term that describes the breakdown of the convolution theorem in first order?
I would like to understand better why and how the convolution theorem magically works on $\mathbb{T}^d$ but then fails on (most?) manifolds, and if there isn't a generalization of it that works on them.
A highly related but not identical question is Products of eigenfunctions on compact Riemann surfaces

Shouldn't one expect a much nicer theory on a homogeneous manifold like $\mathbb T^d$ than on a random one?

I suppose so, but if the nice theory breaks in a continuous and even differentiable fashion we should be able to study the first order behavior of that failure.
